# Processing of OpenStreetMaps (OSM) in c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, openstreetmap

I want to process OSM files and the best would be to do it all within C++. My goal is to be able to get grayscale maps, eventually I am considering also clustered recognized shapes (circles for round buildings, long 'thick' splines for roads, rectangulars etc.)

Anyway, the question is to you, can you push me into proper direction, what shall I use to be able to process .osm for my purpose?

Never worked with them before, neither with too much with various c++ libraries, so it'd take me lot of time before I on my own recognize where to go. I am aware of processes of feature detection and description, yet don't know if they also apply in this case.

Please help me out,
regards.

Answer (score 2):

OSM files are actually just XML files with a relatively simple schema.

The main problem here is that they usually are big,  sometimes very big, so the easy way to handle XML files (load them into memory and use some kind of DOM to get to the values) is probably not the best idea. Moreover, a lot of the data in these OSM files is probably not very interesting for your purposes, so you would be wasting a lot of memory. For example, about half of the bytes are used to specify user names and timestamps.

My advice is to use [`expat`](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) to read the XML file. It it a bit more difficult to use than, say, TinyXML, but it is way faster for big files.

An extra advice: keep around a few OSM files for testing. One small files for quick testing, and a big one (or very big) to test that your algorithm complexity does not explode exponentially without you noticing.